# Reloading rails console blows away custom configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a custom initializer that sets up a bunch of data for some API clients. I have a class that implements configuration. When I run `rails c`, I see the data correctly stored in the configuration. But if I run `reload!`, the configuration is blown away.

config/initializers/rewards.rb

```
RewardsConfig.configure do |config|
  config.register_client(
    key: :giftbit,
    klass: Rewards::Clients::GiftbitRewardsClient,
    client_config: {
      address: ENV['GIFTBIT_API_ADDRESS'],
      token: ENV['GIFTBIT_API_TOKEN'],
      params: {
        'marketplace' => {
          region: '2',
          limit: '1000',
          long_format: true
        }
      }
    }
  )
end
```

lib/rewards_config.rb

```
module RewardsConfig
  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= Configuration.new
  end

  def self.configure
    yield(configuration) if block_given?
  end

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :clients

    def initialize
      @clients = {}
    end

    def register_client(key: nil, klass: nil, client_config: {})
      clients[key] ||= {
        class: klass,
        client_config: client_config
      }
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `rails c`, I can then run `RewardsConfig.configuration` and see that the Giftbit client data is loaded in the `@clients` instance var. But if I run `reload!` and then run `RewardsConfig.configuration`, I see:

`=> #<RewardsConfig::Configuration:0x007fcff37db1d8 @clients={}>`.

I have another initializer for setting configuration data in the Tangocard gem for communicating with the Tangocard API. When I reload the Rails console, the configuration data remains.

Why is the config data getting blown away on my class, which operates almost exactly as this gem does?

Comment: Can you see the `gem`'s implementation?

Comment: yes, it's here: https://github.com/bonusly/tangocard/blob/master/lib/tangocard.rb - as you can see, I pretty much copied their implementation, but I'm not sure why the config data stays when I do `reload!` for Tangocard and not for my custom `RewardsConfig` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is nicely explained in the Rails Guides for [Autoloading and Reloading Constants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-and-initializers).

You can try to assign `RewardsConfig` to a `Constant` variable and after reloading reference to the `clients` will be kept, but you need to remember the variable name so it's not the best way (tried and worked for me).

The second suggestion from the docs is to define the access point which in my opinion is a better option.

Comment: i see - so Rails clears any loaded constants when I run `reload` and will load them as they're referenced in the console, which would explain why the data in `@clients` is no longer there. However, I still don't quite get why the Tangocard data remains.

Comment: actually, i think i get it - because Tangocard is a gem dependency, it gets added to the `$LOADED_FEATURES` array and isn't cleared upon `reload!`, whereas my `RewardsConfig` class is just a class within my app and gets cleared